# how to handle enum type with json2typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I receive a JSON from the back-end that contains an Enum type.

```
{
...,
pst:['SMS','EMAIL'],
...
}
```

This is my Typescript enum class:

```
export enum PostSynchroActions {
  SMS = 'SMS',
  Email = 'Email',
  SocialWall = 'SocialWall',
  Transformation = 'Transformation',
  Clone = 'Clone'
}
```

How can I De-serialize this with json2Typescript library.

This is my line for the typescript class that I use to de-serialize the back-end json.

export class Terminal {
...

@JsonProperty('pst',[PostSynchroActions])
actionPostSynchro:PostSynchroActions[] = [];

...

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PostSynchroActions[data]` if you are sending the keys, otherwise just use `data as PostSynchroActions`. You also need to check for `EMAIL` to equal `Email` so the full function would be:

```
export enum PostSynchroActions {
  SMS = 'SMS',
  Email = 'Email',
  SocialWall = 'SocialWall',
  Transformation = 'Transformation',
  Clone = 'Clone'
}

function postSynchroActionsFromKeys(data: string) {
    if(data === "EMAIL") {
        data = "Email";
    }
    return PostSynchroActions[data as PostSynchroActions] as PostSynchroActions;
}
function postSynchroActionsFromValues(data: string) {
    if(data === "EMAIL") {
        data = "Email";
    }
    return data as PostSynchroActions;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwAoQM4wMoCeiAxgBZQQCCxMAlhItnAN4CwAUHHHgLJ5wBeOAHJeeYQBoOXAKKoAhrQA2gkXMVLJ07hGK15SgOoGVQ0bv1GTWznAAqUeYwBm0BXQarhDp9ldR3ekQbLgBhJQZgL3DI4Q4AXw4OZ2QSD0Q4SFxCEnIqGiDsADEKVABpYAJsAAoAE3kYeQAuOFwoWkQAcwBKFm0uWmc6hvlBASEAIhkeSgBJABkJ3rZbLjW4esbVKYVlCYBufrhE1bgoYBhkKAysbKIyCmp07ABtTdH5Jlv8e7ynwoAunBPpgcD9co8CgxsId2CcUmkgpkwTkHvlniUIKgAGoGZDAGrvFptDo9PqnQbDLbjSbTOaLZZHdbvbbqPaw9YndbnS7XDYjYFfFG-SHPWHxIA)

Comment: Thanks, I will use your code block in a custom de-serializer.  It's a pain in the rear to do a custom deserializer

Comment: Yeah, though if you have JSONschema, you could look at [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv)/[djv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/djv).